# scale_alpha_continuous on log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use scale_alpha_continuous in ggplot on a log scale to generate a figure with lines whose transparency (and color) varies depending on a given value on a log scale, given the wide distribution.
Using the code below, I am able to change the color based on a log scale by adding `trans="log"` but how do I do the same for the transparency (alpha)?

```
p+scale_color_continuous(trans = "log",low="red", high="black")+ scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 1))
```

Many thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `trans = "log"` to the `scale_alpha_continuous()` also.

```
library(ggplot2)
# here is some simulated data
set.seed(2020)
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(100),
                 Y = runif(100),
                 Z = rexp(100, rate = 0.0000001))
# Original plot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, color = Z, alpha = Z)) +
  geom_point(size = 5)
```

[image: scatter plot without log scales]

```
# Log scales
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, color = Z, alpha = Z)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) + 
  scale_alpha_continuous(trans = "log", breaks = c(4e5, 4e6, 4e7)) +
  scale_color_continuous(trans = "log", breaks = c(4e5, 4e6, 4e7))
```

[image: scatter plot with log color and alpha scales]